# Powershell Remove Strings from each line after a match

Tags: powershell

I have a log file with below contents and I need to replace everything after a match inclusive of the match criteria as well using powershell script

**Log File:**

```
 - ABCD,1234,12 Percent (Total: 12 / 100)
 - DEFG,1234,32 Percent (Total: 32 / 100)
 - HIJK,1234,77 Percent (Total: 77 / 100)
 - QWER,1234, (Total: 77 / 100)
```

I would like to get output like below

```
 - ABCD,1234,12 Percent
 - DEFG,1234,32 Percent
 - HIJK,1234,77 Percent
 - QWER,1234,0 Percent
```

I tried regex commands which replaces but not inclusive of the match criteria in powershell and substring never worked too

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I may not be fully understanding your question, but are you looking for something like this?:

```
$Text = 'ABCD,1234,12 Percent (Total: 12 / 100)', 
'DEFG,1234,32 Percent (Total: 32 / 100)', 
'HIJK,1234,77 Percent (Total: 77 / 100)', 
'QWER,1234, (Total: 77 / 100)'
$text | Foreach-Object {
    $_ = $_ -replace ' \(.*'
    if ($_ -notlike "*Percent*"){
        $_ = $_ + "0 Percent"
    }
    $_
}
```

Output:

```
ABCD,1234,12 Percent 
DEFG,1234,32 Percent 
HIJK,1234,77 Percent 
QWER,1234,0 Percent
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
ABCD,1234,12 Percent (Total: 12 / 100)
DEFG,1234,32 Percent (Total: 32 / 100)
HIJK,1234,77 Percent (Total: 77 / 100)
QWER,1234, (Total: 77 / 100)
```

**Script**

```
Get-Content ".\Log.txt" | ForEach-Object { 
    $result = "$_".Substring(0, "$_".IndexOf("(") -1)
    if(!$result.EndsWith("Percent"))
    {
        $result += "0 Percent"
    }
    $result
}
```

**Output**

```
ABCD,1234,12 Percent
DEFG,1234,32 Percent
HIJK,1234,77 Percent
QWER,1234,0 Percent
```

[image: code]

Answer (score 0):

Or use `switch`:

```
$result = switch -Regex -File 'Path\To\The\LogFile.log' {
    '^(.+\d+\sPercent).*' { $matches[1] }
    '(,\s\([^)]+\))$'     { $_ -replace [regex]::Escape($matches[1]), ',0 Percent'}
    default { $_ }
}

# show on screen
$result

# write to (new) file
$result | Set-Content -Path 'Path\To\The\NewLogFile.log'
```

Output:

```
 - ABCD,1234,12 Percent
 - DEFG,1234,32 Percent
 - HIJK,1234,77 Percent
 - QWER,1234,0 Percent
```